# What will be the value of $η$ such that for $m<η$, the zeta function ζ(m) will diverge?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

So for example; $ζ(1)$ will diverge and $ζ(1.1)$ will diverge. So I want to find the value of $η$ such that the zeta function will diverge if we take a value less than it and converge if we take that value or above it. From my observation $η\approx1.3$. Has the complete value of this been found out?

Comment: Why does $\zeta(1.1)$ diverge?

Comment: The zeta function does not diverge. What diverges is a particular infinite series which represents the zeta function in a particular region of the complex plane. That series diverges when the real part of $s$ is at most one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\zeta(s)$ [converges for all $s>1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).